# CSS ignoring @font-face declarations

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have two @font-face assignments in my CSS. Only the second/last one ever renders, though they are nearly identical.

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'callunaregular';
    src: url('callunaregular/Calluna-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('callunaregular/Calluna-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('callunaregular/Calluna-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('callunaregular/Calluna-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('callunaregular/Calluna-Regular-webfont.svg#callunaregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'bodonitownregular';
    src: url('bodonitownregular/bodonitown-webfont.eot');
    src: url('bodonitownregular/bodonitown-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('bodonitownregular/bodonitown-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('bodonitownregular/bodonitown-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('bodonitownregular/bodonitown-webfont.svg#bodonitownregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I think it's a simple fix, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Edit:

```
<body style='background-color:white'>
<div align='center' style='position:absolute;left:500px;top:89px'> 
    <a id='title' href='home.html' > 
        <span style="font-family: callunaregular; font-size: 79px;">Open Mic Night</span>
    </a>
```

is identical to setting the font-family to Times.

Comment: The problem is in something you haven't shown.  What style rules *use* Calluna Regular? Do they match the HTML you think they should match? Look at the network trace panel in your browser's debugger; is the font getting downloaded at all, do you get an HTTP error, or what?

Comment: I had a problem similar to this once. Have you tried checking your HTML `<link>` tags to ensure they would include the following attribute: `rel="stylesheet"` ?

Comment: I don't have anything in my CSS specifically using Calluna. Instead I just explicitly call it in some spans.

Comment: @MaddyByahoo Where did you put this CSS code? Did you properly include the CSS file within your HTML page?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the CSS shows up fine.

Comment: You say only the last one renders...  if you get rid of the last one (making callunaregular the last one), then does callunaregular render?

Comment: No. If callunaregular is the only one, it doesn't render. If there's another one before it, it does.

Comment: Sounds like there might be a problem with the code immediately BEFORE this code block.

Comment: My CSS begins with the @font-faces...

Comment: @andi Wow, apparently you can't have comments in CSS?! That single one-line deletion fixed everything!! Thank you!

Comment: Comments in CSS should look like this: /* foo */  -- just in case you had the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this one causes the problem?:

`'callunaregular/Calluna-Regular-webfont.svg#bodonitownregular'`

See, after the hash?

Comment: Good catch, but I changed it to #callunaregular but it didn't do anything.